# How to create a jar for android application?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I have a java project which I want to use to create an Android app. I have created the jar file using Eclipse -> export -> , but when I use the jar file in Android. It finds the class but the app does not work. It crashes saying "`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myapp-1, /system/lib]]`". If I dont call the java class from the jar in the app, the app works fine! I was wondering if this is due to jar file creation problem or anything? Can anyone help? How do I create a jar from Eclipse so that I can use in Android?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you aren't putting the .jar file into the proper location. The correct location to put the .jar file is the `{project}/libs` folder. If you do this, it should work correctly.

Comment: yes. i did that. then i  tried with both checked & unchecked in order n export. no LUCK yet.